# GPT Destroyed - help!

Tags: startup, partition

Recently I decided to triple boot my MacBook Pro (2015) and have run into a bit of trouble.  After a few days of a working machine (linux-MAC-Windows via refind), my machine suddenly stopped working.

After a bit of googling I ran a few commands I shouldn't have and now I am utterly lost.  I have destroyed my gpt and am basically starting from scratch.

I can't simply reformat because internet recovery mode does not see any disks upon which it can install the operating system.[image]

Comment: Can you get to Disk Utility in Recovery Mode? Should be able to format the drive from there then reinstall.

Comment: No drives showing in Disk util (in recovery mode) ... I think due to the fact that the gpt has been 'destroyed'

Comment: ok - so create a live system of OS X on my thumb drive? - I have what I need here, just need to know where to start

Comment: I assume it takes about 40 minutes or even more. Several reboots will be performed. At the end you will be asked to create a user and set up networking. Then install TeamViewer (a remote desktop tool), launch the app and send the credentials to klanomath(at)googlemail.com.

Comment: Apologies for my newness to this site / interface but I don't yet have reputation enough to chat.  Alas, 7 minutes left on my install.

Comment: If you are done with configuring macOS don't install TeamViewer 13 but TV 12: https://www.teamviewer.com/download/previous-versions/ I can't install TV 13 because my system is too old and TV 12 doesn't want to work with TV 13 pears.

Comment: credentials sent

Comment: it booted me klanomath