# How to recover APFS encrypted partition table

Tags: macos, partition, filesystem, data-recovery

I was trying to install an encrypted Debian on my Macbook pro 2017 but somehow Debian erased the partition table and now when I boot in the macOS recover I can only see 3 unformated partition with a GUID partition table. No more APFS encrypted drive.

I don't have any backup and I have to recover my files, is it possible / how can I do it?

I can give more log if needed, I just don't know what.

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:           Linux Filesystem                         536.9 MB   disk0s1
   2:           Linux Filesystem                         511.7 MB   disk0s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         250.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk17

/dev/disk18 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk18
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32                         15.5 GB    disk18s1

-bash-3.2# gpt -r /dev/disk0 
gpt: unknown command: /dev/disk0
-bash-3.2# gpt -r            
usage: gpt [-frv] [-p nparts] command [options] device ...
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk0
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: error: bogus map
gpt show: unable to open device 'disk0': No such file or directory
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk1
    start     size  index  contents
        0        1         PMBR
        1        1         Pri GPT header
        2       32         Pri GPT table
       34        6         
       40  3925512      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3925552   262151         
  4187703       32         Sec GPT table
  4187735        1         Sec GPT header
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk1
```

I feel that what happen is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967385/how-do-i-recover-the-apfs-partition-of-a-macbook-using-ubuntu)

Comment: on APFS only the data inside the volume is encrypted, not the partition table itself. If you could edit in the question what `diskutil list` and `gpt -r` [for the disk in question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307401/5472), we might be able to offer some guidance relative to a fix or just seek professional data recovery options. Was your data backed up in any manner before this erasure?

Comment: Very nice edits and getting the gpt command right from my limited hint. I hope someone has a good idea for you